# selenium webdriver have to find element from dynamic dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I hope that someone could help me solving this.
Have to choose from dynamic dropdown only one which is active, disabled no. Following is part of dropdown.

```
<option value="1-2639425" disabled="disabled">21/10/2017 16:45 - Felipe Arantes - Josh Emmett (No odds available)</option>
<option value="1-2636744" disabled="disabled">21/10/2017 16:45 - Jim Wallhead - Warlley Alves (No odds available)</option>
<option value="1-2633126">21/10/2017 20:00 - Donald Cerrone - Darren Till</option>`
```

There are few things which confuses me:

- I have to choose only the one(s) option which does not have 'No odds available' in it - they are clickable (those without 'No odds available')
- It is not necessary that the one which can be chosen reside on 3rd position (as shown above) - can be first, second, 50th
- Actually, I have to choose first clickable one (no matter where reside in option list)

  Tried with this code but without any success:

  ```
  Select dropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to 3rd option")));
  dropdown.selectByIndex.selectByIndex(2);
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  ```

Please assist.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the options using `getOptions()` and then get the first option without "No odds available" text or `disabled` attribute. Then you can use `Select` to select an option using the `value` attribute

Also, `Select` class doesn't get an option as parameter, it gets the parent `<select>` tag as parameter

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to the select tag")));
List<WebElement> options = dropdown.getOptions();

for (WebElement option : options) {
    // if (option.getAttribute("disabled") != null)
    if (!option.getText().contains("No odds available")) {
        String value = option.getAttribute("value");
        dropdown.selectByValue(value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have several steps to finish, and in one step I have driver1, driver2, .. in order to choose different dropdowns 
I used this
' Select dropdown3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"tip-event\"]")));
  List<WebElement> options = dropdown3.getOptions();

  for (WebElement option : options) {
      // if (option.getAttribute("disabled") != null)
      if (!option.getText().contains("No odds available")) {
          String value = option.getAttribute("value");
          dropdown3.selectByValue(value);
          break;
      }
  }
  
  Thread.sleep(5000);'
throws er

Comment: Error is:
'Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element <span class="column large-3 button secondary navigation-next is-disabled" id="post-tip-bottom-tab-2" '
        It actually pass step and show me that next step is disabled
       What did wrong on step which explained above?
      Waht I did wrong?

Comment: @Zoran New question should be posted as a new question.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for bodering - your solution is OK, I made mistake when tried to implement it.